# CSS animation, absolute position go off screen to right and come back from left

Tags: css, animation

I am making a site with some clouds. I want the clouds to move across the screen from left to right. I have the clouds moving but am a little stuck on one aspect. I want some of the clouds to be on screen when the page loads.  I want those clouds to start moving and go off screen to the right, then come back in from the left and keep on going.

Here is an image that may explain it a little better:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="clouds">
    <div class="firstCloud">        
        <svg id="svgCloud" data-name="clouder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 348 164"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-5</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M348,107.5a54.5,54.5,0,0,1-94.87,36.61,77.55,77.55,0,0,1-81.57-1.43A73,73,0,0,1,71,145.07,42.48,42.48,0,1,1,49.61,71.59,73,73,0,0,1,154.85,26.84,77.51,77.51,0,0,1,287.16,53.37,53,53,0,0,1,293.5,53,54.5,54.5,0,0,1,348,107.5Z"/></svg>
    </div>  
    <div class="secondCloud">
        <svg id="svgCloud2" data-name="cloud2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 291 124"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d3dddb;}.cloud2Fill{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-4</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M2.29,123.5A41,41,0,0,1,58.37,74.12l.32.14.24-.25A45.72,45.72,0,0,1,91.5,60.5q1.14,0,2.25.06l.43,0,.09-.41a76,76,0,0,1,148.46,0l.09.4h.41l1.27,0a46.06,46.06,0,0,1,46,46,45.53,45.53,0,0,1-3.26,17Z"/><path class="cloud2Fill" d="M168.5,1a75.53,75.53,0,0,1,73.74,59.23l.18.81.82,0,1.26,0a45.49,45.49,0,0,1,42.4,62H2.66A40.53,40.53,0,0,1,58.17,74.57l.63.29.49-.49A45.2,45.2,0,0,1,91.5,61c.75,0,1.5,0,2.23.06l.85,0,.18-.83A75.51,75.51,0,0,1,168.5,1m0-1A76.52,76.52,0,0,0,93.78,60.06Q92.66,60,91.5,60A46.35,46.35,0,0,0,58.58,73.66,41.52,41.52,0,0,0,1.92,124H287.58A46.5,46.5,0,0,0,244.5,60l-1.28,0A76.53,76.53,0,0,0,168.5,0Z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="thirdCloud">
        <svg id="svgClouds3" data-name="clouds2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 329 139"><defs><style>.cloud2Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-6</title><path class="cloud2Fill" d="M329,125a40.09,40.09,0,0,1-2.52,14H14.9A61.28,61.28,0,0,1,0,99C0,64.21,29.33,36,65.5,36a67.34,67.34,0,0,1,30,7A86,86,0,0,1,236.42,31.37,55.53,55.53,0,0,1,311,83.5a56.67,56.67,0,0,1-.55,7.75A39.93,39.93,0,0,1,329,125Z"/></svg>
    </div>    
</div>

.firstCloud {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 150px;
    animation: move 50s linear 2s infinite;
    width: 150px;
}

.secondCloud {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 200px;
    animation: move 55s linear 0s infinite backwards;
    width: 150px;
}

.thirdCloud {
    top: 250px;
    left: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    animation: move 60s linear 10s infinite backwards;
    width: 150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);}
  to {-webkit-transform: translateX(2000px);}
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/west4me/pen/ypBKME)

I've searched around but I think my Google-Fu has failed me in what to search for. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't have the time to post a detailed answer to you right now, but I have made this codepen two years ago, I think it can help you : https://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/WbyrOe

Comment: Thanks @MehdiBrillaud, it's close but not quite. The cloud that is starts positioned on screen, when it comes back it is coming back at its starting point, not off screen.

Comment: You can still use @MehdiBrillaud their pen, if you change the starting position of the clouds, it'll start off screen instead of the starting position

Comment: @Simplicity thanks, but I want the starting position to be on screen. I don't want the sky empty of clouds on load. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You could just make a "start cloud" of some sort, which just moves to the right and have all other clouds start from off the screen and loop them instead.

Comment: @WilliamCunningham I'm pretty sure my bottom cloud starts within the screen (it's starts with a margin-left of 20%). But in my pen, at the end of the animation, the cloud pops again in the middle of screen. To avoid that, you have to use a little trick. Just set animation-iteration-count to 1, and start another infinite animation coming from the left of the screen when the first animation ends. I'm not sure if it's clear, I'll try to make you a pen tomorrow if you haven't figure it out (still not having the time right now).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the solution I proposed in the comments before:

You can make an initial cloud (`.initalCloud`) that just slides out of the screen and gets replaced with the regular `.firstCloud` afterwards.

```css
.clouds {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}

.initialCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 150px;
  animation: moveFirst 5s linear .2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  width: 150px;
}

.firstCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  top: 150px;
  animation: move 5s linear 5s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  top: 200px;
  animation: move 8s linear 0s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.thirdCloud {
  top: 250px;
  left: -30%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 11s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    left: -30%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  from {
    left: 50%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="clouds">
  <div class="initialCloud">
    <svg id="svgCloud" data-name="clouder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 348 164"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-5</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M348,107.5a54.5,54.5,0,0,1-94.87,36.61,77.55,77.55,0,0,1-81.57-1.43A73,73,0,0,1,71,145.07,42.48,42.48,0,1,1,49.61,71.59,73,73,0,0,1,154.85,26.84,77.51,77.51,0,0,1,287.16,53.37,53,53,0,0,1,293.5,53,54.5,54.5,0,0,1,348,107.5Z"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="firstCloud">
    <svg id="svgCloud" data-name="clouder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 348 164"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-5</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M348,107.5a54.5,54.5,0,0,1-94.87,36.61,77.55,77.55,0,0,1-81.57-1.43A73,73,0,0,1,71,145.07,42.48,42.48,0,1,1,49.61,71.59,73,73,0,0,1,154.85,26.84,77.51,77.51,0,0,1,287.16,53.37,53,53,0,0,1,293.5,53,54.5,54.5,0,0,1,348,107.5Z"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="secondCloud">
    <svg id="svgCloud2" data-name="cloud2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 291 124"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d3dddb;}.cloud2Fill{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-4</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M2.29,123.5A41,41,0,0,1,58.37,74.12l.32.14.24-.25A45.72,45.72,0,0,1,91.5,60.5q1.14,0,2.25.06l.43,0,.09-.41a76,76,0,0,1,148.46,0l.09.4h.41l1.27,0a46.06,46.06,0,0,1,46,46,45.53,45.53,0,0,1-3.26,17Z"/><path class="cloud2Fill" d="M168.5,1a75.53,75.53,0,0,1,73.74,59.23l.18.81.82,0,1.26,0a45.49,45.49,0,0,1,42.4,62H2.66A40.53,40.53,0,0,1,58.17,74.57l.63.29.49-.49A45.2,45.2,0,0,1,91.5,61c.75,0,1.5,0,2.23.06l.85,0,.18-.83A75.51,75.51,0,0,1,168.5,1m0-1A76.52,76.52,0,0,0,93.78,60.06Q92.66,60,91.5,60A46.35,46.35,0,0,0,58.58,73.66,41.52,41.52,0,0,0,1.92,124H287.58A46.5,46.5,0,0,0,244.5,60l-1.28,0A76.53,76.53,0,0,0,168.5,0Z"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thirdCloud">
    <svg id="svgClouds3" data-name="clouds2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 329 139"><defs><style>.cloud2Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-6</title><path class="cloud2Fill" d="M329,125a40.09,40.09,0,0,1-2.52,14H14.9A61.28,61.28,0,0,1,0,99C0,64.21,29.33,36,65.5,36a67.34,67.34,0,0,1,30,7A86,86,0,0,1,236.42,31.37,55.53,55.53,0,0,1,311,83.5a56.67,56.67,0,0,1-.55,7.75A39.93,39.93,0,0,1,329,125Z"/></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 6):

I set a keyframe 50% and 50.001% to make cloud teleport right to left.
Here is code pen:
https://codepen.io/sqfkw1578/pen/abzypXN?editors=1100

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#svgCloud {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  animation: move 4s linear infinite;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) translateY(-50%);
  }
  50.001% {
    transform: translateX(-60vw) translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgCloud" data-name="clouder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 348 164"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-5</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M348,107.5a54.5,54.5,0,0,1-94.87,36.61,77.55,77.55,0,0,1-81.57-1.43A73,73,0,0,1,71,145.07,42.48,42.48,0,1,1,49.61,71.59,73,73,0,0,1,154.85,26.84,77.51,77.51,0,0,1,287.16,53.37,53,53,0,0,1,293.5,53,54.5,54.5,0,0,1,348,107.5Z"/></svg>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` on `body` is essential to keep such an animation not breaking mobile view.

Answer (score 2):

use of `left` property instead of `translateX()` because you can use of percent in left and detect end screen.

```css
.clouds {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}

.firstCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  top: 150px;
  animation: move 10s linear 2s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  top: 200px;
  animation: move 15s linear 0s infinite;
  width: 150px;
  }

.thirdCloud {
  top: 250px;
  left: -150px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 20s linear 5s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {left: -150px;}
  to {left: 100%;}
}
```

```html
  <div class="clouds">
    <div class="firstCloud">        
        <svg id="svgCloud" data-name="clouder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 348 164"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-5</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M348,107.5a54.5,54.5,0,0,1-94.87,36.61,77.55,77.55,0,0,1-81.57-1.43A73,73,0,0,1,71,145.07,42.48,42.48,0,1,1,49.61,71.59,73,73,0,0,1,154.85,26.84,77.51,77.51,0,0,1,287.16,53.37,53,53,0,0,1,293.5,53,54.5,54.5,0,0,1,348,107.5Z"/></svg>
    </div>  
    <div class="secondCloud">
        <svg id="svgCloud2" data-name="cloud2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 291 124"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d3dddb;}.cloud2Fill{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-4</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M2.29,123.5A41,41,0,0,1,58.37,74.12l.32.14.24-.25A45.72,45.72,0,0,1,91.5,60.5q1.14,0,2.25.06l.43,0,.09-.41a76,76,0,0,1,148.46,0l.09.4h.41l1.27,0a46.06,46.06,0,0,1,46,46,45.53,45.53,0,0,1-3.26,17Z"/><path class="cloud2Fill" d="M168.5,1a75.53,75.53,0,0,1,73.74,59.23l.18.81.82,0,1.26,0a45.49,45.49,0,0,1,42.4,62H2.66A40.53,40.53,0,0,1,58.17,74.57l.63.29.49-.49A45.2,45.2,0,0,1,91.5,61c.75,0,1.5,0,2.23.06l.85,0,.18-.83A75.51,75.51,0,0,1,168.5,1m0-1A76.52,76.52,0,0,0,93.78,60.06Q92.66,60,91.5,60A46.35,46.35,0,0,0,58.58,73.66,41.52,41.52,0,0,0,1.92,124H287.58A46.5,46.5,0,0,0,244.5,60l-1.28,0A76.53,76.53,0,0,0,168.5,0Z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="thirdCloud">
        <svg id="svgClouds3" data-name="clouds2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 329 139"><defs><style>.cloud2Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-6</title><path class="cloud2Fill" d="M329,125a40.09,40.09,0,0,1-2.52,14H14.9A61.28,61.28,0,0,1,0,99C0,64.21,29.33,36,65.5,36a67.34,67.34,0,0,1,30,7A86,86,0,0,1,236.42,31.37,55.53,55.53,0,0,1,311,83.5a56.67,56.67,0,0,1-.55,7.75A39.93,39.93,0,0,1,329,125Z"/></svg>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Use jquery if you want starts animation of middle screen Just for one time:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.firstCloud,.secondCloud,.thirdCloud').animate({
     left:"100%"
  },10000,function(){$(this).addClass('anim')})
})
```

```css
.clouds {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}

.firstCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 150px;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left:  50%;
  top: 200px;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  width: 150px;
  }

.thirdCloud {
  top: 250px;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  width: 150px;
}


.anim {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {left: -150px;}
  to {left: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clouds">
    <div class="firstCloud">        
        <svg id="svgCloud" data-name="clouder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 348 164"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-5</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M348,107.5a54.5,54.5,0,0,1-94.87,36.61,77.55,77.55,0,0,1-81.57-1.43A73,73,0,0,1,71,145.07,42.48,42.48,0,1,1,49.61,71.59,73,73,0,0,1,154.85,26.84,77.51,77.51,0,0,1,287.16,53.37,53,53,0,0,1,293.5,53,54.5,54.5,0,0,1,348,107.5Z"/></svg>
    </div>  
    <div class="secondCloud">
        <svg id="svgCloud2" data-name="cloud2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 291 124"><defs><style>.cloud1Fill{fill:#d3dddb;}.cloud2Fill{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-4</title><path class="cloud1Fill" d="M2.29,123.5A41,41,0,0,1,58.37,74.12l.32.14.24-.25A45.72,45.72,0,0,1,91.5,60.5q1.14,0,2.25.06l.43,0,.09-.41a76,76,0,0,1,148.46,0l.09.4h.41l1.27,0a46.06,46.06,0,0,1,46,46,45.53,45.53,0,0,1-3.26,17Z"/><path class="cloud2Fill" d="M168.5,1a75.53,75.53,0,0,1,73.74,59.23l.18.81.82,0,1.26,0a45.49,45.49,0,0,1,42.4,62H2.66A40.53,40.53,0,0,1,58.17,74.57l.63.29.49-.49A45.2,45.2,0,0,1,91.5,61c.75,0,1.5,0,2.23.06l.85,0,.18-.83A75.51,75.51,0,0,1,168.5,1m0-1A76.52,76.52,0,0,0,93.78,60.06Q92.66,60,91.5,60A46.35,46.35,0,0,0,58.58,73.66,41.52,41.52,0,0,0,1.92,124H287.58A46.5,46.5,0,0,0,244.5,60l-1.28,0A76.53,76.53,0,0,0,168.5,0Z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="thirdCloud">
        <svg id="svgClouds3" data-name="clouds2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 329 139"><defs><style>.cloud2Fill{fill:#d1dbd9;}</style></defs><title>Untitled-6</title><path class="cloud2Fill" d="M329,125a40.09,40.09,0,0,1-2.52,14H14.9A61.28,61.28,0,0,1,0,99C0,64.21,29.33,36,65.5,36a67.34,67.34,0,0,1,30,7A86,86,0,0,1,236.42,31.37,55.53,55.53,0,0,1,311,83.5a56.67,56.67,0,0,1-.55,7.75A39.93,39.93,0,0,1,329,125Z"/></svg>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: The clouds reappear in the middle of the screen, which is most definitely not the desired result.

Comment: The left 50% is used because OP **wants** the cloud to start in the middle, but reappear on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

I made this quickly just to show you the concept.

At first, I set the starting position of the cloud at 50px from the left, then I set an animation, but with only one iteration.

Then I made a second cloud with an infinite animation but I also set a delay on it. That way, you give the illusion that the first animation is looping, even if it's two different elements and animations.

This is the only way I can think using CSS only.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.clouds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.clouds.cloud1 {
  left: 50px;
  animation: cloud1 20s linear 1;
}

.clouds.cloud2 {
  left: -50px;
  animation: cloud1 20s 10s linear 1;
}

@keyframes cloud1 {
  0% {
    left: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 3000px;
  }
}

@keyframes cloud2 {
  0% {
    left: -50px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 3000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="clouds cloud1"></div>
 <div class="clouds cloud2"></div>
</div>
```