# Make clouds float across screen and group divs into one object?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm experimenting on creating a scene through css of clouds floating in the sky... here is the current code :

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Super-Legend-Boy';
    src: url('./Documents/assets/fonts/Super-Legend-Boy.eot');
    src: url('./Documents/assets/fonts/Super-Legend-Boy.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('./Documents/assets/fonts/Super-Legend-Boy.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('./Documents/assets/fonts/Super-Legend-Boy.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./Documents/assets/fonts/Super-Legend-Boy.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('./Documents/assets/fonts/Super-Legend-Boy.svg#Super-Legend-Boy') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

html,body {
   
    font-family: 'Super-Legend-Boy';

    background: #95e9d0
}



.cloud {
    position: relative;
  box-shadow: thistle;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 7px rgb(65, 63, 63));
    animation: move 50s linear 0s infinite;

}

.cloud-one{
    top: 200px;
    left: 10%px;
    animation: move 50s linear 0s infinite;
}

.cloud-two{
    left: 50%;
    animation: move 50s linear 0s infinite;
}

.cloud-three{
    top: 210px;
    left: 75%;
    animation: move 50s linear 0s infinite;
}

.cloud-four{
    left: 80%;
    animation: move 50s linear 0s infinite;


}

.cloud-five{
    left: 10%;
    animation: move 50s linear 0s infinite;


}

.cloud-six{
    top:210px;
    left: 25%;
    animation: move 50s linear 0s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);}
  to {-webkit-transform: translateX(2000px);}
}



p {
    text-align: center;
   
}

.circle {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

.circle-one {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 40px;
}

.circle-two {
height: 60px;
width: 100px;
top: 40px;

}

.circle-three{
height: 80px;
width: 100px;
top: 20px;
left: 100px;
}

.circle-four {
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
top: 50px;
left: 150px;
}

div.container3 p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }

.line {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 60%;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: grey;
   
}
```

```html
<body font-family:'Super-Legend-Boy'>



<div class="cloud cloud-one"><div class="circle circle-one"></div>
<div class="circle circle-two"></div>
<div class="circle circle-three"></div>
<div class="circle circle-four"></div> </div>

<div class="cloud cloud-two"><div class="circle circle-one"></div>
<div class="circle circle-two"></div>
<div class="circle circle-three"></div>
<div class="circle circle-four"></div> </div>

<div class="cloud cloud-three"><div class="circle circle-one"></div>
<div class="circle circle-two"></div>
<div class="circle circle-three"></div>
<div class="circle circle-four"></div> </div>

<div class="cloud cloud-four"><div class="circle circle-one"></div>
<div class="circle circle-two"></div>
<div class="circle circle-three"></div>
<div class="circle circle-four"></div> </div>

<div class="cloud cloud-five"><div class="circle circle-one"></div>
<div class="circle circle-two"></div>
<div class="circle circle-three"></div>
<div class="circle circle-four"></div> </div>

<div class="cloud cloud-six"><div class="circle circle-one"></div>
<div class="circle circle-two"></div>
<div class="circle circle-three"></div>
<div class="circle circle-four"></div> </div>

<div class="container3"> <p> The Choice is Yours </p></div>

<div class="line" background-color=grey></div>



</body>

</html>
```

Two things i am trying to achieve.

1. Making the clouds move across the page and come back around on the other side (if that makes sense) Not sure where to start on animation.
2. I would like to group each cloud into one object, so that when i add a drop shadow, it would go around the whole cloud as opposed to each circle shape within each cloud. Also thinking the clouds would need to be grouped in order for them to move as a whole .

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754999/css-animation-absolute-position-go-off-screen-to-right-and-come-back-from-left/47755864) should solve your query.

Comment: Hi there thanks a lot! that helped, I have another question i just ran into and was wondering if you could help! I feel like i'm missing something in the font face i'm trying to add... (code updated) but font is not showing.. :/

Answer (score 0):

As given below, you can use simple css animations to move your cloud around

```css
html,
body {
  background: #d6deff;
}

.cloud {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: thistle;
}

.cloud-one {
  top: 200px;
  left: 10%px;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.cloud-two {
  left: 50%;
}

.cloud-three {
  top: 210px;
  left: 75%;
}

.circle {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle-one {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 40px;
}

.circle-two {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 40px;
}

.circle-three {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100px;
}

.circle-four {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {0: -50%;}
  to {left: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud cloud-one">
  <div class="circle circle-one"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-two"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-three"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-four"></div>
</div>

<!-- <div class="cloud cloud-two">
  <div class="circle circle-one"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-two"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-three"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-four"></div>
</div>

<div class="cloud cloud-three">
  <div class="circle circle-one"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-two"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-three"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-four"></div>
</div> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Each cloud can be animated separately if required or you could get them to move together.

This snippet puts delays on the animations of the second and third slide so they look as if they are moving independently. Remove those for uniform movement.

A drop shadow is put on each cloud, not on each circle. Obviously this needs alteration depending on wha effect is wanted.

Each animation goes from the cloud being just to the left of the left side and moving to just right of the right side.

```css
html,
body {
  background: #d6deff
}

.cloud {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: thistle;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0 20px gray);
  animation: move infinite 10s linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw + 200%));
  }
}

.cloud-one {
  top: 200px;
}

.cloud-two {
  top: 100px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.cloud-three {
  top: 250px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circle {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle-one {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 40px;
}

.circle-two {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 40px;
}

.circle-three {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100px;
}

.circle-four {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60%;
  left: 20%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud cloud-one">
  <div class="circle circle-one"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-two"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-three"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-four"></div>
</div>

<div class="cloud cloud-two">
  <div class="circle circle-one"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-two"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-three"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-four"></div>
</div>

<div class="cloud cloud-three">
  <div class="circle circle-one"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-two"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-three"></div>
  <div class="circle circle-four"></div>
</div>
<div class="line" background-color=grey></div>

</html>
```

Of course, there is some tidying up to be done depending on exactly what you want the initial conditions and the timings to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped! Was really useful seeing your code , appreciate it!

I have updated mine above to reflect the changes however, I can't seem to see the reason for why my font is not appearing for the text in the center of the page... any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

(For future reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754999/css-animation-absolute-position-go-off-screen-to-right-and-come-back-from-left/47755864) solved the original question.)

In regards to the font query as per the comment, you don't need the `<body font-family:'Super-Legend-Boy'>` in your HTML, what you have in your CSS is sufficient.

It appears that it's been written correctly, but your url links for the font files may be wrong. Check your url links are correct and if it is, try removing the initial `.` before `/documents../ etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried playing around with the path but can't seem to get it to work, is there a way to retrieve path files (right click>view path) or something?

Thanks for the help. You all have been amazing!

Comment: @Jonty This question should be closed as a duplicate then, not answered. [answer]